# How to save a figure with multiple overlapping plots?

Tags: matplotlib, adobe, pdflatex

I am plotting multiples signals overlapping in one figure using matplotlib and then saving it in pdf/eps using `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`, the problem is that when I try to insert the figure in a pdf-latex file, it takes like 1.5 min to load because it starts rendering every plot. Is there any way to properly save or create these plots in one figure?

The final pdf works perfectly when I use preview on macOS, regularly when I use edge or chrome navigators and it is a disaster if I use adobe-reader. I am looking for a multiplatform solution.

Comment: Have you tried saving as an image format (png, jpg), and then insert that in your pdf? In formats like eps it could be that all the overlapping data is still included as overlapping points, but with image formats all the info below the most on top one is removed.

Comment: Hi, No, I haven't. I want to have vectorial-graph images.